# Solving $\lambda U^{\dagger}V -\bar{\lambda} V^{\dagger}U = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given an $A \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, is it always possible to solve for $U,V \in SU(n)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda U^{\dagger}V -\bar{\lambda} V^{\dagger}U = A$?

Cross posted from MSE as no answer appeared.

Comment: See answers for the crossposted question at [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362747/solving-lambda-u-daggerv-bar-lambda-v-daggeru-a).

Comment: Please wait a bit longer before cross-posting -- say, at least a week or so.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is skew hermitian, it is normal and we may assume that $A=diag(i\theta_j)$ where the $(\theta_j)_j$ are known real numbers.
We choose $U=I$ and $V=diag(e^{i\alpha_j})$ where the $(\alpha_j)_j$ are unknown real numbers. The required equality can be written: for every $j$, $\lambda e^{i\alpha_j}-\bar{\lambda}e^{-i\alpha_j}=i\theta_j$. We choose $\lambda=\sup_j\{|\theta_j/2|\}+1$; then the conditions over the $(\alpha_j)_j$ become: for every $j$, $\sin(\alpha_j)=\dfrac{\theta_j}{2\lambda}$ and we are done.

Comment: That's great thanks! Will this still be possible is $U$ is also given? I.e. given $A$ and $U$ can we always solve for $V$?

Comment: and $\lambda$ I should have said.

Comment: Actually $V \mapsto UV$ does the job if $U$ is given and $V$ is your $V$ from your answer.